# Acrobat Reader not found in iOS Safari navigator.plugins

Tags: javascript, ios

So I know for certain that Adobe Acrobat is installed on the ipad we're testing.  Detecting it however has been problematic.  Using the navigator.plugins object works fine for detecting acrobat reader on all browsers except the iOS Safari browser.

```
Console.log("Plugins List:\n");
for (var key in navigator.plugins) {
  Console.log(navigator.plugins[key].name);
}
```

On OSX Safari this returns:

- Adobe Acrobat NPAPI Plug-in, Version 10.1.4
- Schockwave Flash
- Java Applet Plug-in
- QuickTime Plug-in 7.7.1
- WebKit build-in PDF
- undefined
- namedItem
- refresh
- item

On iOS Safari this returns:

- QuickTime Plug-in
- undefined
- namedItem
- refresh
- item

And again I know for sure that Acrobat Reader is installed.  Unfortunately we're hamstrung to only using Acrobat Reader due to the incompatibility of the signature software we use with any other pdf reader.  Is there any other way to detect whether Adobe Acrobat is installed on the iOS version of Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrobat Reader for iOS is not a browser plugin — it's just an application. It does not affect the way PDFs are displayed in Safari.

There is no way to determine whether an application is installed in iOS from the browser. But, in your case, it hardly matters, because the functionality of Safari is the same whether it's installed or not.